# Checking for Add method in mocked DbContext not working with NSubstitute

Tags: nsubstitute

I'm trying to verify that the `Add` method was called on the database context, so I tried this:

```cs
var context = Substitute.For<LampContext>();

// Call code the results in a context.Add being made

_context.ReceivedWithAnyArgs(1).Add(Arg.Any<ChangeLog>);
```

That's saying that no matching call was made, but if I debug the test and step through the code, I do see the `Add` call happening. What's the proper way to make this check?

Comment: What version/edition of EF are you using?

Comment: @dai Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version 7.0.10

Comment: Are you sure the code is calling `DbContext.Add` rather than `DbContext.SomeDbSetMember.Add`? (personally, I'd' never use `DbContext.Add` - only the `DbSet<T>.Add` method instead because otherwise it's not immediately obvious which entity collection the entitity gets added to.

Comment: @dai Yes, it calls it like this:  `_context.Add(new ChangeLog { ... });`